# How to cipher UTF-8 beyond A-Z in python?

Tags: python, encryption, utf-8, hex

Many years ago, I made a program in C# on Windows which "encrypts" text files using (what I thought was) caeser chipher.

Back then I wanted more characters than just A-Z,0-9 and made it possible but never thought about the actual theory behind it.

Looking at some of the files, and comparing it to [this website](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm), it seems like the UTF-8 is being shifted.

---

I started up a Windows VM (because I'm using Linux now) and typed this: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

It generated a text that looks like this in hexadecimals (Shifted 15 times):

```
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f c280 c281 c282 c283 c284 c285 c286 c287 c288 c289
```

How can I shift the hexadecimals to look like this?

```
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a
```

Or are there any easier/better methods of doing this?

---

## UPDATE

I'm using Python 3.5.3, and this is the code I have so far:

```
import sys

arguments = sys.argv[1:]
file = ""

for arg in arguments:
    if arg[0] != "-":
        file = arg

lines = []
with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    result = 0
    for value in list(line):
        #value = "0x"+value
        temp=value.encode('utf-8').hex()
        temp+=15
        if(temp>0x7a):
            temp-=0x7a
        elif(temp<=0):
            temp+=0x7a
        #result = result + temp
    print (result)
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the C# source code available for the moment. I can try to find it

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what the underlying problem is. Why can't you just subtract from each character the value 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input is ASCII text, the simplest solution is to encode/decode as ASCII and use the built-in methods `ord()` and `chr()` to convert from character to byte value and vice versa.

Note that the `temp` value cannot be less than 0, so the second if-statement can be removed.

NB: This is outside the scope of the question, but I also noticed that you're doing argument parsing yourself. I highly recommend using `argparse` instead, since it's very easy and gives you a lot extra for free (i.e. it performs error checking and it prints a nice help message if you start your application with '--help' option). See the example code below:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(dest='filenames', metavar='FILE', type=str, nargs='+',
                    help='file(s) to encrypt')
args = parser.parse_args()

for filename in args.filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rt', encoding='ascii') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        result = ""
        for value in line:
            temp = ord(value)  # character to int value
            temp += 15
            if temp > 0x7a:
                temp -= 0x7a
            result += chr(temp)  # int value to character
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert hex back and forth between [integers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int) and [hex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#hex) using `int()` and `hex()`.  However, the `hex()` method only works on integers.  So first you need to convert to an integer using base=16.

```py
hex_int = int(hex_str, 16)
cipher = hex_int - 15
hex_cipher = hex(cipher)
```

Now apply that in a loop and you can shift your results left or right as desired.  And you could of course condense the code as well.

```py
result = hex(int(hex_string, 16) - 15)

#in a loop
hexes = ['70', '71', 'c280']
ciphered = []
for n in hexes:
    ciphered.append(hex(int(n, 16) - 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int('somestring'.encode('utf-8').hex(),16)` to get the exact values on that website. If you want to apply the same rules to each character, you can do it in a character list. You can use

```
import codecs

def myencode(character,diff):
    temp=int(character.encode('utf-8').hex(),16)
    temp+=diff
    if(temp>0x7a):
        temp-=0x7a
    elif(temp<=0):
        temp+=0x7a
    result=codecs.decode(hex(temp)[2:],"hex").decode("utf-8")
    return result
```

`diff` should be the shift for the cipher (It could be an integer). `encode('utf-8')` converts string to byte array and `.hex()` displays bytes as hex. You should feed this function only one character of a string at a time so there would be no issues shifting everything.

After you are done with the encoding you need to decode it in to a new character which you can do by library `codecs` to convert from integer to `byte` (`char`) and then return it back to a string with `decode("utf-8")`

Edit: Updated, now it works.

Comment: What should the `diff` be? I would assume it is an integer (the shift), but I get an error message saying: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`. Also, should it be `.hex()` or `.encode("hex")` ?

Comment: @Typewar The `diff` is the shift as you guessed. I am updating my answer to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Now I get this error `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`. I tried adding 0x in front of the string like this `temp=str("0x"+character).encode('utf-8').hex()` but it didn't help. I can see that by adding 0x in front, the int value changes from 70 to 307870

Comment: You should not need to add 0x in the beginning as a string. Whatever this function returns is already hexadecimal

Comment: And please take note i did design this cipher in range between 0 and 7a. You also might want to tweak that too.(by changing 0 and 7a values)